# How to reverse following bitwise operation (((flags >> 4) & 31) +1) so that I can get value of flags back

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How to reverse below operation so that I can get value of flags back 
`(((flags >> 4) & 31) +1)`

Comment: There isn't a unique solution

Comment: `flags2 = (result-1)<<4`. But you won't get back the four lower order bits lost during the `>> 4`, nor any bits beyond bit #8 which are lost through the `&31`.

Comment: You can rebuild `flags` only if is multiple of 16 (and unsigned if memory helps)

Comment: @LaurIvan and if the original `flags` is less than 512.

Comment: @JimmyB then all you need is to be a multiple of 16